# Android app to linux process mapping

Tags: android, linux, performance, process, android-source

We know that in the lower level each application in Android is a linux process. But I was wondering what does it mean if a same application has been listed in 2 process when I do a ps in adb. So I was curious how does the second instance of the app got created? Does that mean an app has the capability to create a kernel level thread?

If so I was trying to map which circumstances would fork a new process. Is it the usage of a Service in an app? Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add android:process tag, you can create another process for any components and the same app running in two different users will have different processes

Comment: Yes I agree with the above. But does a Service in android run in the same process as that created for the app? Does it make a separate process?

Comment: it runs in the same process unless you specify a separate process in manifest file